# posix shell にて 32bit right rotation を実現したい

Tags: sh, posix

posix shell だけでどこまで計算できるものなのかを知りたいと思い、 bit 演算がどうやったら実現できるのか知りたいと思いました。(特に、 sha256/md5 などを実装してみようとしていた)

32 bit の right rotation bit shift 演算を実現したいです。これは、どうやったらできるでしょうか。 shell には [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04) があり、数値型としては signed long は保証されていること、 bit 演算子たちがあることから、たぶん実現できそうだ、とは思っています。しかし、 long の bit 長って取得できたんだっけ、それをふまえて正しい bit 演算って何なんだっけ、と思っているので、質問しています。

Comment: bashの勉強中です。面白そうな質問でしたのでbashで実装してみました。

Answer (score 1):

何をやりたいのかいまひとつわかりませんが、32 bit 整数のビットのシフト、ローテートならこんな感じでしょうか。(効率等は考えていません)

```
#!/bin/sh

## 32 bit 整数の MSB
msb=2147483648
## 33 bit 整数の MSB
msbx2=$((msb*2))

## 32 bit を越える整数を扱えるかどうかのテスト
[ $msbx2 -gt $msb ] || exit 1

while read v; do
  ## 32 bit 整数に丸める
  v=$((v % msbx2))
  printf 'input         %8x\n' $v
  printf 'right shift:  %8x\n' $(( v / 2 ))
  printf 'left shift:   %8x\n' $(( v * 2 % msbx2 ))
  printf 'right rotate: %8x\n' $(( v / 2 + v % 2 * msb))
  printf 'left rotate:  %8x\n' $(( v * 2 % msbx2 + v / msb))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

## 【 ビット演算によるright rotation】

ビット演算を使用したright rotationを`bash`で実装してみました。

**【コード】**

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX_BIT_NUM=64
func(){
    BIT_NUM=$1
    n=$2
    data=$3
    printf "BIT_NUM=%d data=%s n=%-2d " ${BIT_NUM} ${data} ${n}

    DATA_MASK=$((  ~((-1)<<(BIT_NUM))  ))
    if [ ${DATA_MASK} = 0 ]; then DATA_MASK=-1; fi  #over flow
    RIGHT_MASK=$((~(-1<<n)))
    LEFT_MASK=$(((-1<<n)&DATA_MASK))

    #範囲外bitクリア
    data=$((data&DATA_MASK))
    #rightデータ退避
    right=$((data&RIGHT_MASK))
    #nビット右シフト
    data=$((data>>n))
    #ローテートする部分を0クリア
    data=$(( data&(~(RIGHT_MASK<<(BIT_NUM-n))) ))
    #退避したrightデータをローテートしてセット
    data=$((  data|(right<<(BIT_NUM-n))  ))
    printf "rotete data=0x%016x(%d)\n" ${data} ${data}
}
```

**【実行結果】**

```
BIT_NUM=32 data=16#a0b0c0d0 n=0  rotete data=0x00000000a0b0c0d0(2695938256)
BIT_NUM=32 data=16#a0b0c0d0 n=1  rotete data=0x0000000050586068(1347969128)
BIT_NUM=32 data=16#a0b0c0d0 n=2  rotete data=0x00000000282c3034(673984564)
BIT_NUM=32 data=16#a0b0c0d0 n=3  rotete data=0x000000001416181a(336992282)
BIT_NUM=32 data=16#a0b0c0d0 n=4  rotete data=0x000000000a0b0c0d(168496141)
BIT_NUM=32 data=16#a0b0c0d0 n=31 rotete data=0x00000000416181a1(1096909217)
BIT_NUM=32 data=16#a0b0c0d0 n=32 rotete data=0x00000000a0b0c0d0(2695938256)
BIT_NUM=64 data=16#a0b0c0d0a0b0c0d0 n=0  rotete data=0xa0b0c0d0a0b0c0d0(-6867777429458337584)
BIT_NUM=64 data=16#a0b0c0d0a0b0c0d0 n=4  rotete data=0x0a0b0c0d0a0b0c0d(723685415265700877)
BIT_NUM=64 data=16#a0b0c0d0a0b0c0d0 n=8  rotete data=0xd0a0b0c0d0a0b0c0(-3413534175366434624)
BIT_NUM=64 data=16#a0b0c0d0a0b0c0d0 n=31 rotete data=0x416181a1416181a1(4711189214792876449)
BIT_NUM=64 data=16#a0b0c0d0a0b0c0d0 n=32 rotete data=0xa0b0c0d0a0b0c0d0(-6867777429458337584)
```

## 【 整数のビット長】

`bash`における`long`がどういうものか分かっていませんが、整数のbit長をカウントしてみました。
　　**結果**は**64**でした。

**【コード】**

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
for ((d=1; d != 0; d<<=1))
do
    ((count+=1))
done
printf "count=%d\n" ${count}
```

---

## 【使用したbashのバージョン】

GNU bash, バージョン 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)